# modern replacement for dip meters?

Tags: transformer, inductor, multimeter, inductance, resonance

Dip meters are no more manufactured (and old ones are no more calibrated). These devices were thought to be very useful to a large game of ham radio and electrical engineers.

[image]

Usually, when a device disappears, this is because there are cheaper or more powerful devices on the market. 
Yet, it is not obvious what has actually replaced dip meters.

My question is: 
What is the modern replacement for dip meters?

or, to put in a more practical way, when you have to measure the resonance frequency of a circuit (without connecting it physically to a measurement device), what do you do?

Answer (score 5):

The market has been completely taken over by antenna analyzers that report the complex impedance of the device under test. Some have an optional coupling coil that can be used with the internal bridge and VFO to emulate the grid dip function.